# How do I "control" a pixel array in Android? (Blur)

Tags: java, android, bitmap, blur

I'm trying to create a very simple blur effect on a bitmap and although I do know that there are algorithms out there already, I'd still like to understand how they work. This is the code I have so far, there's nothing in there that resembles a blur algorithm at the moment, I just wanted to know how the setPixels method works a little better.

```
    public void blurTest(Bitmap sentBm) {
         Bitmap blurredBitmap = sentBm;
         int bmWidth = sentBm.getWidth();
         int bmHeight = sentBm.getHeight();

         int[] pixels = new int[bmWidth * bmHeight];           

         sentBm.getPixels(pixels, 0,bmWidth,0,0,bmWidth,bmHeight);

         for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
             pixels[i] = Color.BLACK;
         }

         blurredBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, bmWidth, 0, 0, bmWidth, bmHeight);
```

I've done some research on how blur algorithms work and while I do understand the theory behind them, I don't know how to apply it to each pixels. For example, how much is pixel is being blurred is often expressed using weight numbers. A pixel that is two pixels away from the center has a weight of  0.065 or something like that for example. It makes sense but how do I programmatically scan each pixel and add weights to the nearby pixels? I just need the simplest possible algorithm there is, to learn from.

Or do make things even more simple - how do I add 25% pure blue to all pixels? This is what confuses me the most, how to add and subtract value from the individual pixels.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Look into the methods `Color.red()`, `green()`, and `blue()`. With these, you can extract the color component values, adjust them as you like, then re-compose the color with `Color.argb()`.

Comment: That's kind of what I'm trying to do but I don't know what to adjust them to. For example, Blue is -16776961 (0xff0000ff) but how do I add 1/16 of that a pixel?

Comment: The `Color.blue()` method should return a value between 0 and 255, inclusive. Multiply that by 17/16, check that it's not >255, then get your new color by calling `Color.argb(a, r, g, newBlue)`.

Comment: Ah, thank you that helped a lot! I accidentally looked at the constant Color.BLUE which made me rather confused.

Making an actual blur effect is gonna be way harder though of course. But now I have a slightly better understanding of how the pixels work.

Comment: No sweat! Glad to help. You might check the following question for an example to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218438/android-box-blur-algorithm